# Basics questions about request handlers in liferay

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, web.xml

I have started working in liferay since last few weeks. I have a few questions about liferay plugin developement and they are

1. Can we have a servlet inside a plugin?
2. If yes then which one can have the plugin? is it a portlet or a hook or is it an ext?
3. How can I map a servlet to `http://liferayhost:8090/url/callback` as we do in the web.xml?
4. Can we write a web.xml for a portlet or a hook?

Please help me understand these topics.

Answer (score 0):

*Can we have a servlet inside a plugin?*

If you are creating a `Liferay Hook`, your `doRun` method will get `Request` and `Response` objects which you can use to process the `Request` and `Response` respectively.

For eg., you can get Session Id, Cookies etc through your Request object.

`session=request.getSession(false);`

`Cookie[] cookies =  request.getCookies();`

And you can use `Response` object to do a redirect,

`response.sendRedirect("/PathToYourPage");`

So, you can get almost everything which you can get as a Servlet.

If you are developing a `Portlet` plugin, then, remember its a `Portlet` that you are developing and not a `Servlet`. In `Portlet` if you want `Request` and `Response` objects, you can use below code

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServletRequest")); 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response = (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServletResponse"));
```

On the same lines you can give a try for `Ext`s

If you are developing a `Theme` plugin, I really don't understand what you want to achieve there as a `Servlet`.

But still what you can do is, include one JSP page in your Theme's `vm` files under `templates` folder.

```
$theme.include($themeServletContext, "/myJSP.jsp")
```

This JSP page can be placed under `WebContent` folder. In this `myJSP.jsp` , through JSTL/Scriplets you can get `Request/Response` objects

I hope this will also anwer for your 2nd question.

*How can I map a servlet to http:/liferayhost:8090/url/callback as we do in the web.xml?*

`8090` will be your port number that you would have configured in your Application server by mentioning the index.

`url` value will be your Web application name (war file) name that you would have configured in your web server's (eg Apache) `uriworkers.properties`. `callback` will be your `Servlet`s URL pattern that you would configured in `web.xml` of your application.

*Can we write a web.xml for a portlet or a hook?*

You can write `web.xml` for both `Portlet` and `Hook`. In case of Hooks, although no exception will be thrown if you have basic configuration in `web.xml`, but I dont understand what you want to do there.